# Mac OS X GUI in Assembly

Tags: objective-c, assembly

Is it possible to make a Mac OS X GUI in assembly bypassing the need for Objective C like Windows and Linux allow?

Comment: Yes, you can write any program in assembly that you could write in Objective-C.  It might not be very fun, though. What's your real question?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course.  You can write an entire application in nothing but assembly, if you want.

What you can't avoid is calls into the framework APIs to setup and run the application.

Thus, you'll be spending a bunch of time writing assembly that sets up call sites into objc_msgSend() and/or framework C functions.

Create a new project in Xcode and then go to any source file and "show assembly".   There is the assembly version and you could certainly use that as your starting point.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. Most of the major libraries which you need to write a GUI application for Mac OS X (e.g, Cocoa and AppKit) are written in Objective C, and must be called from code that's written in that language as well. While it's technically possible to replicate the same effects in assembly, at that point you're basically just writing ObjC in a really awkward way.

There is an older GUI library for Mac OS X (Carbon) that is usable from C (and thus could potentially be used from assembly as well), but it is only available in 32-bit mode, and is deprecated. Don't use it for new code.

Comment: You can write an app in pure assembly, you'll just be setting up the call frames and JMP'ing to objc_msgSend() frequently.

Comment: Of course. But, like I said, at that point you're really just writing ObjC in assembly.

Comment: Yup -- which is no different than Windows/Linux (unless their security model is just flat out non-existent).